# Ember createRecord error

Tags: javascript, web, ember.js

I'm trying to follow the [Ember getting started guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/), but with a couple differences. Most notably, I'm using precompiled templates. Here's what I've got, without the dirty template code:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    VERSION: '1.0.0',
    ready: function () {
        console.log('App version: ' + App.VERSION + ' is ready.');
    }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({

    //Use fixtures - I've tried this without the extend too
    adapter : DS.FixtureAdapter.extend()
});


App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("todos", { path: "/" });
});


App.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('todo');
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {

        this.render('todos', {outlet:'main'});
    }
});

App.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.Todo.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Learn Ember.js',
    isCompleted: true
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: '...',
    isCompleted: false
},
{
    id: 3,
    title: 'Profit!',
    isCompleted: false
}];

App.TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        createTodo: function() {

            // Get the todo title set by the "New Todo" text field
            var title = this.get('newTitle');

            if (!title) { return false; }
            if (!title.trim()) { return; }

            // Create the new Todo model
            var todo = this.store.createRecord('todo', {
                title: title,
                isCompleted: false
            });

            // Clear the "New Todo" text field
            this.set('newTitle', '');

            // Save the new model
            todo.save();
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, the todos route renders the `todos` template into the `main` outlet. All of that works perfectly. However, the trouble I'm having now is with `this.store.createRecord` in the `TodosController`. Every time it is called (by me pressing enter in the input field of the app), I get a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. I know the function is being called, because I can log console output right before the call to `this.store.createRecord`.  I'm on version 1.6.1 of ember, and 0.14 of ember-data, if that helps.

If anyone has any ideas as to why this could be happening, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your ember-data version. If you installed it with bower, you can change the version in your bower.json (`"ember-data": "~1.0.0-beta.8"`) and run `bower install`.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to define the Application adapter like this:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
```

rather than

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({

    //Use fixtures - I've tried this without the extend too
    adapter : DS.FixtureAdapter.extend()
});
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it then gives me a Uncaught TypeError: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `store:main`, and ember doesn't even load...

Comment: Just to be sure, are you including ember-data.js?

Comment: Yes, I have jquery, handlebars, ember, and ember-data concatenated into my lib.js. Besides that, my `this.store.find('todo')` functions as expected in the route :(